# R: creating uneven levels of factor for a numeric variable

Tags: r, quantile

I have a set of values (100000 entries) ranging from -0.20 to +0.15, which are return percentages.

Bulk of the values lies between +3.5% and -3.5%

I am looking to convert this into a factor such that:

- any return between -0.035 to +.035 are equally binned in 0.05 increments and
- anything between -0.2 to -.035 is binned as one factor and
- anything between 0.05 to .15 is binned as one factor variable.

Any thoughts on how I can achieve this in R? I did try `cut`, but it seems to bin only in equal increments.

Comment: if you `?cut`, the `breaks=` argument lets you define custom break points.

Comment: ...so maybe `cut(stuff, breaks=c(-0.2, -0.035, seq(-0.03, 0.035, by=0.005), 0.05, 0.15))`?

Answer (score 1):

So I generated the vector that holds the values (out of uniform distribution)

```
 library(data.table)
 set.seed(555)#in order to be reproducible
 N <- 100000#number of pseudonumbers to be generated
 min1=-0.035#arbitrary limits
 max1=0.035#idem

 samp <- runif(N,min = -0.2,max = 0.15)#create the vector 

 level1 <- as.factor(ifelse(samp<=min1,paste0("(",min(samp),",",min1,"]"),NA))#create the first level 
 level2 <- as.factor(ifelse(samp>=max1,paste0("[",max1,",",max(samp),")"),NA))#create the second level
 incr <- 0.005
 level3 <- cut(samp,seq(min1, max1, by = incr))#create the intermediate levels 

 dt <- data.table(samp,level1,level2,level3)#put all together
 mylevels <- na.omit(unlist(matrix(t(dt[,-1]))))#the vector that contains in which range the samp belongs to
```

For better visualization of results:

```
mylevels<-factor(mylevels,levels= unique(mylevels))
dt2<-dt[,.(samp,levels=mylevels)]
            samp                      levels
     1: -0.07023653 (-0.199996188434307,-0.035]
     2:  0.10889991   [0.035,0.149995080730878)
     3:  0.04246077   [0.035,0.149995080730878)
     4: -0.01193010              (-0.015,-0.01]
     5:  0.02607736                (0.025,0.03]
   ---                                        
 99996: -0.04786692 (-0.199996188434307,-0.035]
 99997: -0.08700210 (-0.199996188434307,-0.035]
 99998:  0.09989973   [0.035,0.149995080730878)
 99999:  0.10095336   [0.035,0.149995080730878)
100000: -0.05555869 (-0.199996188434307,-0.035]
```